# Top 2 by group in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to get the Top 2 units by company here. Table is called 'Table (3)'

[image]

I want to be able to populate the column like this -

[image]

I had tried  `Column = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT('Table (3)','Table (3)'[Company]),SUM('Table (3)'[Units]))` but got a circular error.

The other way I think of doing this - not very effective - is use the TOPN and do a UNION by each company so each company would have a table of it's own TOPN value.

I know how to do this on power query already using Table.MaxN but want to do this on DAX

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rank like this:

```
Rank = 
VAR CurrUnits = 'Table (3)'[Units]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        RANK.EQ ( CurrUnits, 'Table (3)'[Units] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table (3)', 'Table (3)'[Company] )
    )
```

From there, you can throw away ranks other than 1 and 2 if you choose to.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand how this can work but it works. I don't understand how assigning the Table (3)'[Units] into a variable will work but if I select this 'Table (3)'[Units] column, it doesn't seem to appear?

Comment: When it's inside the CALCULATE, the context is different. So to keep things simpler, I set the value I want before trying to use it inside of CALCULATE.